# How to process String of concatenated JSON blobs into List of Strings with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a String that contains concatenated JSON objects of varying structure that I want to turn into a list of strings.  For example, given this input:

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}{
  "wibble": "wobble"
}
```

...I would like to have a `List<String>` object output that looks like this:

```
[{"foo":"bar"}, {"wibble":"wobble"}]
```

Ideally I want to do this without implementing the JSON specification myself.  I have found a naive implementation using Jackson that works if my initial string does **not** contain extra whitespace:

```java
public List<String> extractJsonBlobs(String json) throws IOException {
    if (json.length() == 0) return ImmutableList.of();

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readValue(json, JsonNode.class);

    return new ImmutableList.Builder<String>()
            .add(jsonNode.toString())
            .addAll(extractJsonBlobs(
                    json.substring(jsonNode.toString().length())
            ))
            .build();
}
```

```java
// this input works as described
String workingString = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}{\"wibble\":\"wobble\"}";

// this input fails
String problemString = "{\n" +
        "  \"foo\": \"bar\"\n" +
        "}{\n" +
        "  \"wibble\": \"wobble\"\n" +
        "}";
```

The issue is that `jsonNode.toString().length()` always gives me the smallest representation possible (13 for the first object in this case) when what I need is the original unprocessed string length for the concatenated JSON object (18 for the first object in this case).  How can I either get that "original" string length *or* otherwise iterate through these JSON objects? 
 Thanks!

Comment: Simply remove new lines.

Comment: The problem isn't just the newline chars, unfortunately—any extra whitespace will have the same issue.

Comment: Do a trim() then as well. Otherwise you will need to parse the json to some Java Object, and then parse it back into a string as you see fit.

Comment: trim() eliminates leading and trailing whitespace, but I would also need to remove whitespace in the middle.  And I can't remove _all_ whitespace because there could be valid whitespace within a string value.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I landed on involved using a parser (instead of trying this only with `ObjectMapper`), but using `JsonNode` and again relying on its `toString()` behavior to give me a JSON string representation:

```java
    public List<String> extractJsonBlobs(String json) throws IOException {
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory(new ObjectMapper());
        JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(json);
        Iterator<JsonNode> messages = parser.readValuesAs(JsonNode.class);

        return Streams.stream(messages)
                .map(m -> m.toString())
                .collect(toList());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
    public List<String> extractJsonBlobs(String json) {

        JsonMapper mapper = new JsonMapper();
        List<String> jsonBlobs = new ArrayList<>();

        MappingIterator<JsonNode> it = mapper.readerFor(JsonNode.class)
                .readValues(json)) {
            while (it.hasNextValue()) {
                jsonBlobs.add(it.nextValue().toString());
            }

        return jsonBlobs;
    }
```

You can try-catch it for JsonEOFException in case that the data is not complete (e.g. coming from a stream) to prepend a buffer with the missing data :

```
    public List<String> extractJsonBlobs(String json) {

        JsonMapper mapper = new JsonMapper();
        List<String> jsonBlobs = new ArrayList<>();

        int lastSuccessfulParseCharLocation = 0;

        try (MappingIterator<JsonNode> it = mapper.readerFor(JsonNode.class)
                .readValues(json)) {
            while (it.hasNextValue()) {
                jsonBlobs.add(it.nextValue().toString());
                lastSuccessfulParseCharLocation = (int) it.getCurrentLocation().getCharOffset();
            }


        } catch (JsonEOFException e) {
            charBuffer.position(lastSuccessfulParseCharLocation);
            Arrays.fill(prependChars, '\0');
            charBuffer.get(prependChars, 0, (charBuffer.length()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return jsonBlobs;
    }
```

For context, charBuffer is a `CharBuffer` and prependChars is a `char[]`